# In Google sheets write a script to perform a regexreplace function on selected cells only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I frequently paste data from documents to a sheet and the formatting is not ideal.

Is there a function that will allow me to run regexreplace functions on slected cells only (that will strip the cell of invalid characters).

This is the custom menu item that will run the script:

```
//custom menu
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu');
  var item = menu.addItem('Tidy Text','tidyText');
  item.addToUi();
}

//actual regexreplace function
function tidyText() {
  //can't figure this bit out after trying multiple sources
}
```

This is the regexreplace that I use in a helper column to do the strippign down:

`=REGEXREPLACE(B3, "[^0-9a-zA-Z-,.!#'@ ~ ]", "")`

For example data before stripping:

`Apples       123-1234-12345          ( golden delicious    Quantity:4   )`

Desired output:

`Apples 123-1234-12345 golden delictions Quantity 4`

Incidentally how can you trim whitespaces etc in this script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `Is there a function that will allow me to run regexreplace functions on slected cells only (that will strip the cell of invalid characters).`, when a cell is selected, you want to convert the following situation.

  - From

    ```
      Apples       123-1234-12345          ( golden delicious    Quantity:4   )
    ```
  - To

    ```
      Apples 123-1234-12345 golden delictions Quantity 4
    ```
  - In your sample value, it seems that `delicious` is changed to `delictions`. But, I guessed that this might have been miscopied.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. And, reopen Google Spreadsheet.

In this script, from your expected result, the simple trigger of `onSelectionChange` is used. So, when you use this script, please select a cell. By this, the script is automatically run.

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.map(c =>
    c.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z-,.!#'@~: ]/g, "").replace(/:/g, " ")
  ));
  range.setValues(values).trimWhitespace();
}
```

Or, if you want to manually run the script, please use the following script. In this script, please run the function `sample` after you select the cells. By this, the cell values are converted.

```js
function sample() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.map(c =>
    c.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z-,.!#'@~: ]/g, "").replace(/:/g, " ")
  ));
  range.setValues(values).trimWhitespace();
}
```

#### Testing:

When the 1st script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

`Apples       123-1234-12345          ( golden delicious    Quantity:4   )` is converted to `Apples 123-1234-12345 golden delicious Quantity 4`.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample value of `Apples       123-1234-12345          ( golden delicious    Quantity:4   )`. When you use this script for other values, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [trimWhitespace()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#trimwhitespace)

Comment: @Google Sheets Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.